# Dialog API Office Add-in not works in Outlook 2016

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-js

I am working on Outlook web Add-in, to Display sign-in page in a dialog. I used Dialog API to do that , It works fine in owa(Outlook web) but not in Outlook 2016 desktop (Version - 1702).

```
 Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://www.google.lk/', {height: 30, width: 20});
```

Comment: Can you give anymore information, error raised by javascript?
See this blog post to know debugging possibilities in Outlook desktop https://keluro.com/programming/2016/10/29/the-many-ways-of-office-addins-debugging/

Comment: @BenoitPatra Thanks for the blog post. I used f12 Chooser to debug Outlook. But its not getting any console error. You have any experience on Dialog API on Outlook 2016? Please share it.

Comment: @BenoitPatra when getting an detailed error , I got error code 12004 (domain is not trusted)

Comment: @BenoitPatra Thanks for your blog post. Found the error and fixed it. [Open url need to be same domain in the Addin]